# How to remove ".0" in a Big Decimal value but retain decimal value more than 0?

Tags: java

How can I remove ".0" in this value?
30.0 > should be 30

But will still display the decimal value if more than 0?
example: 30.5 -> display this still

Answer (score 4):

You could call [`BigDecimal#stripTrailingZeros()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros--) (and then [`toPlainString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString--)). Something like

```
BigDecimal[] arr = new BigDecimal[] { new BigDecimal("30.0"), new BigDecimal("30.5") };
for (BigDecimal bd : arr) {
    System.out.println(bd.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
30
30.5
```